# Toastr JS Setting fadeAway value

Tags: javascript, alert, toastr

I am using a cool alert js library  Project: https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr

I wanted to fadeOut the following alter after a period of time.
Looking at the toastr.js file, I do see the options are there.
I just dont know how to access the property 'fadeAway'

```
toastr.info('Processing...');
```

I tried

```
toastr.info('Processing...', fadeAway:1000);
```

How do I use the fadeAway by passing in a parameter ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Before you call toastr.info, set  the option you choose. For example:

```
toastr.options.fadeOut = 2500;
```

You can see many of the options in the demo here: [toastr demo](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

These are the defaults. You can override many of them:

```js
options = {
  tapToDismiss: true,
  toastClass: 'toast',
  containerId: 'toast-container',
  debug: false,
  fadeIn: 300,
  fadeOut: 1000,
  extendedTimeOut: 1000,
  iconClass: 'toast-info',
  positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
  timeOut: 5000, // Set timeOut to 0 to make it sticky
  titleClass: 'toast-title',
  messageClass: 'toast-message'
}
```

Answer (score 48):

With version 2.0.3 you do the following to make the toastr display longer:

```
toastr.success('Hello World', 'New Message', { timeOut: 9500 });
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  I need a longer timeout so that I have a chance to see the notification, now that Microsoft Edge has put the download pop-up box in the upper right corner, covering my notification!

Answer (score 6):

You can also pass any options in a parameter. But the parameter must be an object. For your example you can use this:

```
toastr.info('Processing...', { fadeAway: 1000 });
```

PS: also keep in mind that fadeAway is deprecated in the current version (2.0.3).