# toastr.js: How to override default parameters for entire project

Tags: javascript, timeout, toastr

I can use custom values for showing a `toastr`. Also, checked-out this question's answers. [Toastr JS Setting fadeAway value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14631844/617185)

But, my question is that is there any way i can override `toastr`'s default options once which will be applicable to my whole project.

for example, I want `"timeOut": "2500"` to be set for my whole project only mentioning it only once, instead of default `"timeOut": "5000"`.

Comment: Did you try set timeout using `toastr.options.timeOut = 30;`.

Comment: don't know why it is downvoted without any explanation for being it a "bad" question.

Comment: @NarendraCM as far as i understood that that will not set it project-wise.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a small change in the `toastr.js` file.

**Go to:** `getDefaults()` method in `toastr.js` file.
 And change the `timeOut: 5000,` to `timeOut: 2500,`

Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, it's a hackish way which i am already using. I wanted to know if there's an "API"-ed way. Thanks anyway, mate (y)